# What is the difference between constrained and unconstrained models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, spss, difference-in-difference, constraint

I have a question what is the difference between constrained and unconstrained model or freely estimated model.

I am trying to test for chi square difference between them to determine discriminant validity, do I add covariance arrow in the constrained model and assign number one to the covariance and the unconstrained model do I simply remove number one or remover the arrow.

I am using CFA in AMOS.

Please check this paper they used it for DV "A Technological Pedagogical Content Knowledge (TPACK) Scale for Geography Teachers in Senior High School" where they used it in Discriminant Validity"

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph, I am sorry to say.  What is "covariance arrow"?  Why would you assign the number one to the covariance?

Comment: @jbowman Thank you for letting me know, In AMOS there is a covariance one can draw between two constructs to test them like in confirmatory factor analysis models. There are papers suggesting that someone can test the constrained and unconstrained models and get the chi square to see if it is significant. The thing is I do not know what do they mean by that how to create that in AMOS is it just covariance or what. Please check this paper "A Technological Pedagogical Content Knowledge (TPACK) Scale for Geography Teachers in Senior High School" where they used it in Discriminant Validity